# Android Animation - animate when selecting

Tags: android, animation

How do I do this (see animation starting from 12 seconds in the video). http://www.google.com/tv/

Is the blue selection a image which needs a translate animation from one item to another.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

probably, the individual views are given focus, and the foccused drawables contain the blue border.

[custom buttons](http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=56)

Comment: How do you animate the blue from one image to another? Thanks

Comment: view1.setFocus() - Just be sure to add a foccused state to your views, with the rectangle -> like shown in the tutorial i posted

Comment: will try and let you know. Thanks